# Contents Folder Convention in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, conventions

I am wondering what the history behind the convention for a /contents folder in ASP.NET MVC project is; where it originates; and the reasoning behind it.

Our team is considering to move our /images and /styles out of /contents to decrease the folder levels in the project. It will be nice to know why the convention was in place in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

it is an effort from the Frameworks side to organize your files and it is the "Convention over Configuration" way which most of the MVC frameworks follow so if you follow this convention it will be easy to develop libraries and plugins which can make use of this convention

for.ex. you can build an HtmlHelper call LoadAndPackScripts which will go and look for javascript files in your content directory pack them and include them in your project